# jQuery no está definido PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

en mi página web http://******.com/, al actualizar a php 7 me da el error de Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined cuando está definido al principio de mi index.php

```
$jquery = '';
jimport('joomla.version');
$version = new JVersion();
if(version_compare($version->getShortVersion(), '3.0', '>=')){
    JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
} else {
    JHTML::_('behavior.mootools');
    JFactory::getDocument()->addScript($this->baseurl.'/templates/'.$this->template.'/js/jq.min.js');
}
```

Luego dentro del html del index.php cualquier código jQuery me dice que no está definido
¿Por qué puede ser?

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Pero dónde tienes ese código, debes ponerlo al principio del `head` y no entiendo bien la comparación que haces, por qué no pones simplemente: `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');`

Comment: Buenas!! Muchas gracias por responder. Ese código está al principio del todo antes de empezar con el html, en un apartado de php. Éste código es de una plantilla de joomla y al actualizar a php 7 se me queda la pantalla en blanco. Voy a probar con lo que me dices, muchísimas gracias.